# IC identification - top markings LA50 1XB50

Tags: dc-dc-converter, identification, surface-mount

I need to replace the device in the picture. I believe it's a DC-DC converter IC looking at the circuit around it.

Any ideas what it is or how I identify it?

[image: photo of unknown IC]

Answer (score 4):

> Any ideas what it is or how I identify it?

1. Determine the package type (eg. SOT89-3)
2. Do a Google image search on function, package, and marking code
3. Search for datasheet.
4. Check that pinout and circuit matches device specs.

I searched Google images for "DC/DC LA50" and got this:-

[image]

Then I searched for BL8531 and got [this](http://www.icgu.com/file/upload/201506/18/17-47-29-94-1.pdf):-

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bruce, that really helped me - much appreciated.